# Deserializing different JSON data in one class

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have two json from server.
If request is OK - return this:

```
{"code":0,"content":{"id":"1318916"}}
```

If request is ERROR - return this:

```
{"code":5,"content":[]}
```

When request is OK - this class good work:

```
[JsonObject]
public class JsonResponse
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code", Order = 1)]
   public int Code { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content", Order = 2)]
   public JsonResponseContent Content { get; set; }

   public class JsonResponseContent
   {
      public string Id { get; set; }
   }
}
```

When ERROR - this class good work:

```
[JsonObject]
public class JsonResponse
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code", Order = 1)]
   public int Code { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content", Order = 2)]
   public JsonResponseContent[] Content { get; set; }

   public class JsonResponseContent
   {
      public string Id { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Can it merge to one class for OK and ERROR answer?

Comment: @3dd In first class **public JsonResponseContent Content { get; set; }** in second class **public JsonResponseContent[] Content { get; set; }** When deserialize "OK" answer to first class - no error, when "ERROR" answer to first class - error occurred

Comment: Ah ok sorry, miss read that part

Comment: What happes if you just leave it as JsonResponseContent[] in both cases, then if it's an error that array would just be empty

Comment: @3dd if leave JsonResponseContent[] in both, when if answer "ERROR" - all good, if answer "OK" - error occured.

Comment: @3dd Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'AppTest.JsonClasses.JsonResponse+JsonResponseContent[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: What happens if you change the error response to {"code":5,"content":{}}. Note that I changed the [] to {}

Comment: @3dd If leave JsonResponseContent (no array) and replace [] to {} in answer before deserializing - all good. Thanks

Comment: Pleasure, I'll ad it as an answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the error response to {"code":5,"content":{}}. Note that I changed the [] to {}